# Log4View not showing any messages

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4view

I'm trying to open our log-file in Log4View but it doesn't show any messages.

A sample logfile entry looks like this:

> 15.11.2017 07:56:45.555    Normal    BaseSessionHandler              3x1r0p5hk3utkd1i2iqyqufg        Aktuelle Anzahl Sessions: 6

I've set Log4View up to use a Pattern Layout:
`%d [%t] %level %logger [%x] - %m` but unfortunately that doesnt work...

Do you have an idea why it doesn't show any messages?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems like the pattern layout you use has got not much in common with your actual message structure.

Assuming *BaseSessionHandler* is a logger and *3x1r0p5hk3utkd1i2iqyqufg* is a thread, you should use a pattern similar to this:

*%date{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff} %level %logger %x %m*

Check out [this documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) on the elements of a layout pattern.